# variables reverting to default value

Tags: java, while-loop, instance-variables

I have my program nearly done where their are three classes:  one driver class, one pizza class, and an order class that calculates the order price. My only issue is once I run my code the variables will set through the while loop in the `inputToppings` method of the pizza class and will print the correct values when the `toString` method is called from the pizza class in the order class but in my `getToppingQuantity` method it's passing the default values for the instance variables.  Where am I going wrong here?

```
package edu.ilstu;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pizza
   {

//default pizza is cheese and tomato sauce only

private int alfredo = 0;
private int pesto = 0;
private int tomato = 1;
private int sausage = 0;
private int pepperoni = 0;
private int onion = 0;
private int mushroom = 0;
private int greenPepper = 0;
private int cheese=1;
private char choice;

public int getCheese() {
    return cheese;
}
public int getAlfredo()
{
    return alfredo;
}
public void setAlfredo()
{
    alfredo=1;
    pesto=0;
    tomato=0;
}
public int getPesto()
{
    return pesto;
}
public void setSausage(int sausage)
{
    this.sausage = sausage;
}
public void setPepperoni(int pepperoni)
{
    this.pepperoni = pepperoni;
}
public void setOnion(int onion)
{
    this.onion = onion;
}
public void setMushroom(int mushroom)
{
    this.mushroom = mushroom;
}
public void setGreenPepper(int greenPepper)
{
    this.greenPepper = greenPepper;
}
public void setCheese(int cheese)
{
    this.cheese = cheese;
}
public void setPesto()
{
    pesto=1;
    tomato=0;
    alfredo=0;
}
public int getTomato()
{
    return tomato;
}
public void setTomato()
{
    tomato=1;
    pesto=0;
    alfredo=0;
}
public int getSausage()
{
    return sausage;
}
public int getPepperoni()
{
    return pepperoni;
}
public int getOnion()
{
    return onion;
}
public int getMushroom()
{
    return mushroom;
}

public int getGreenPepper()
{
    return greenPepper;
}
public void inputToppings() {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Input toppings. Enter Q to quit");
        System.out.println("1. Sausage");
        System.out.println("2. Pepperoni");
        System.out.println("3. Onion");
        System.out.println("4. Mushroom ");
        System.out.println("5. Green Pepper");
        System.out.println("6. Cheese");
        System.out.println("7. Alfredo");
        System.out.println("8. Pesto");
        System.out.println("9. Tomato");

        if (choice == 'q' || choice == 'Q') {
            break;
        }
        if (choice == '1') {
            addSausage();
        }
        if (choice == '2') {
            addPepperoni();
        }
        if (choice == '3') {
            addOnion();
        }
        if (choice == '4') {
            addMushroom();
        }
        if (choice == '5') {
            addGreenPepper();
        }
        if (choice == '6') {
            addCheese();
        }
        if (choice == '7') {

            if(alfredo != 1) {
            setAlfredo();
            }
            else 
                System.out.println("No double sauce allowed");
        }
        if (choice == '8'){
            if (pesto != 1) {
                setPesto();
            }
            else
                System.out.println("No double sauce allowed");
        }
        if (choice == '9') {
            if(tomato != 1) {
                setTomato();
            }
            else
                System.out.println("No double sauce allowed");
        }

        choice = sc.next().charAt(0);
    }//end while loop
    sc.close();
}//end of inputToppings method
public void addCheese() {
    if(cheese<2) {
        setCheese(cheese+1);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
}
public void addPepperoni() {
    if (pepperoni<2) {
        setPepperoni(pepperoni+1);
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("Maximum ammount of topping exceeded");
}
public void addSausage() {
    if(sausage<2) {
        setSausage(sausage+1);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Maximum ammount of topping exceeded");
}
public void addOnion() {
    if(onion<2) {
        setOnion(onion+1);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Maximum ammount of topping exceeded");
}
public void addGreenPepper() {
    if(greenPepper<2) {
        setGreenPepper(greenPepper+1);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Maximum ammount of topping exceeded");
}
public void addMushroom() {
    if(mushroom<2) {
        setMushroom(mushroom+1);
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("Maximum ammount of topping exceeded");
}
public String toString() {
    String str ="sausage = " + Integer.toString(sausage)  + " Pepperoni = " + Integer.toString(pepperoni) + "\n" + "Onion = " + Integer.toString(onion) + " Mushroom = " + Integer.toString(mushroom) +"\n" + "cheese = " + Integer.toString(cheese) +"\n" + "Tomato = " + Integer.toString(tomato) + " Pesto = " + Integer.toString(pesto) + " Alfredo = " + Integer.toString(alfredo);
    return str; 
}
public int getToppingQuantity() {
    return sausage+pepperoni+onion+mushroom+cheese;
}
}//end of class
```

here is the order class

```
public class Order
{
final double TAX_RATE = 0.075;
final double BASE_PRICE = 5.00;
final double TOPPING_CHARGE = 0.75;
final double DELIVERY_CHARGE = 0.10;
public char typeOfOrder;
public String storeLocation = "";
Pizza pizza1 = new Pizza();
Customer cust1 = new Customer();

public double calculateSubtotal() {
    double toppingPrice = (pizza1.getToppingQuantity()*TOPPING_CHARGE);
    return BASE_PRICE+toppingPrice;
}
public double calculateSalesTax() {
    return calculateSubtotal()*TAX_RATE;
}
public double calculateDeliveryCharge() {
    return (calculateSubtotal() + calculateSalesTax()) * DELIVERY_CHARGE;
}
public void displaySummary() {

    if (typeOfOrder=='d' || typeOfOrder=='D') {
        System.out.printf("Subtotal $%.2f\n", calculateSubtotal());
        System.out.printf("Sales Tax: $%.2f\n", calculateSalesTax());
        System.out.printf("Delivery Charge: $%.2f\n", calculateDeliveryCharge());
        System.out.printf("Total: $%.2f\n",  calculateSubtotal() + calculateSalesTax() + calculateDeliveryCharge());
        System.out.println(pizza1.getToppingQuantity());
        System.out.println("Thank you, come again!");
    }
    else if (typeOfOrder == 'p' || typeOfOrder == 'P') {
        System.out.println(storeLocation);
        System.out.printf("Subtotal $%.2f\n", calculateSubtotal());
        System.out.printf("Sales Tax: $%.2f\n", calculateSalesTax());
        System.out.printf("Total: $%.2f\n", calculateSubtotal() + calculateSalesTax());
        System.out.println("Thank you, come again!");
    }

}
public char getTypeOfOrder()
{
    return typeOfOrder;
}
public void setTypeOfOrder(char typeOfOrder)
{
    this.typeOfOrder = typeOfOrder;
}
public String getStoreLocation()
{
    return storeLocation;
}
public void setStoreLocation(String storeLocation)
{
    this.storeLocation = storeLocation;
}
}
```

and finally the driver class

```
public class PizzaDriver
{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Customer cust01= new Customer();
    Order order01 = new Order();
    Pizza pizza01 = new Pizza();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to ILSTU Pizza");
    System.out.println("Step 1: Is this for a pickup or delivery?");
    System.out.println("1 Pickup");
    System.out.println("2 Delivery");
    int choice = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Choice: " + choice);

    if (choice==1) {

        order01.setTypeOfOrder('p');
        System.out.println("1. 207 W. North St, Normal, IL");
        System.out.println("2. 208 Landmark Dr, Bloomington, IL");
        System.out.println("3. 1600 W. Market St, Bloomington, IL");
        System.out.println("Which location would you like to pickup from?");
        choice=sc.next().charAt(0);

        if (choice=='1') {
            order01.setStoreLocation("207 W. North St, Normal, IL");
        }
        else if (choice=='2') {
            order01.setStoreLocation("208 Landmark Dr, Bloomington, IL");
        }
        else if (choice=='3') {
            order01.setStoreLocation("1600 W. Market St, Bloomington, IL");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("invalid choice");

        System.out.println("At this stage would you like to quit this order entry process? \n Enter 'Y' to quit or 'N' to continue on to build your pizza.");
        choice=sc.next().charAt(0);
        if (choice=='N'|| choice == 'n') {
            pizza01.inputToppings();
            System.out.println("Your pizza contains the following toppings: \n" + pizza01.toString());
            order01.displaySummary();
        }
        else if(choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y') {
            System.out.println("Thank you, come again!");
        }
    }

    else if (choice == '2') {
        //System.out.println("Step 2: Customer Information");
        order01.setTypeOfOrder('d');
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter your first and last name: \n");
        cust01.setFullName(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Please enter your street address");
        cust01.setAddress(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Please enter your city, state and zip code");
        cust01.setCityStateZip(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Please enter your phone number (10-dights only)");
        String userNumber=sc.nextLine();
        while(true) {
            if (userNumber.length()==10) {
                cust01.setPhoneNumber(userNumber);
                break;
            }
            else if (userNumber.length()!=10) {
                System.out.println("Invalid phone number, Enter a valid one");
            }
            userNumber=sc.nextLine();
        }   
        System.out.println(cust01.toString()+"\n");

        System.out.println("At this stage would you like to quit this order entry process? \n Enter 'Y' to quit or 'N' to continue on to build your pizza.");
        choice=sc.next().charAt(0);
        if (choice=='N'|| choice == 'n') {
            pizza01.inputToppings();
            System.out.println("\n Your pizza contains the following toppings: \n" + pizza01.toString());
            order01.displaySummary();
        }
        else if(choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y') {
            System.out.println("Thank you, come again!");
        }
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("invalid choice");

}
}
```

like I said my program goes through the steps properly but returns the wrong value for the topping variables in the getToppingQuantity method (Note: I didn't include the customer class because it doesn't pertain to my current issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Order` class you have a `Pizza` instance variable, but in your `PizzaDriver` you're creating and using a different `Pizza` object. This is likely the root cause of your issues. (You're also doing the same thing with the `Customer` class.)

This means that

```
System.out.println("\n Your pizza contains the following toppings: \n"
+ pizza01.toString());
```

...and...

```
order01.displaySummary();
```

Refer to different `Pizza` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your while(true) block in inputToppings() will never allow for an exit from the while condition (except in the `break` you provided to quit. Not that while(true) is an unacceptable programming practice, but it can lead to infinite loops. Better to provide a boolean flag, then exit once the value of the flag has changed.